# Can some please suggest me ,how to write xpath for images.Please find below xpath is valid or not

Tags: selenium

I have tried the below locator but no use :

```
//div[@id="SidebarContent"]//a[@href='/catalog/categories/BIRDS']
```

Please help me with the correct locator...

URL:[This is the URL](https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/catalog)

Below are the Username and the Password:-

```
username:Testing
Password:test@123
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not for checking if your code is correct... you can do that in your browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the images or links?

images (or drop the /img if you want the links):

```
xpath="//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'FISH')]/img"
xpath="//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'DOGS')]/img"
xpath="//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'REPTILES')]/img"
xpath="//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'CATS')]/img"
xpath="//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'BIRDS')]/img"
```

I prefer using css selectors its less brittle:

```
css="div#Sidebar div#SidebarContent a[href*='FISH'] img"
css="div#Sidebar div#SidebarContent a[href*='DOGS'] img"
css="div#Sidebar div#SidebarContent a[href*='REPTILES'] img"
css="div#Sidebar div#SidebarContent a[href*='CATS'] img"
css="div#Sidebar div#SidebarContent a[href*='BIRDS'] img"
```